# Is たべにいっている in the sentence 「かれはすしをたべにいっている」 correct?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

I've got this sentence: かれはすしをたべにいっている。

Why is たべ which is たべる followed after by に and then by another verb? Is this correct?

Apparently it means "He is going to eat the sushi."

Comment: I commend you for deciding to learn hiragana, you got this! Does this answer your question? [What does しに行く mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/95585/32952)

Comment: For the ～行っている meaning "has gone (and hasn't returned yet)", see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/53820/9831 (and 
 maybe https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19418/9831 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3140/9831 `彼は日本に行っている He has gone to Japan. (He went to Japan, and is still there.)` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you read with kanji and copy-paste it into a dictionary. If you read in full romaji or kana some ambiguities will arise that will be especially confusing for a beginner.

---

Setting that aside.

> kare wa sushi wo tabe ni itte iru 
> 彼はすしを食べに行っている

食べに is the tricky part

食べ is a noun meaning "eating", it's 食べる in what's called masu stem 食べ(ます).

masu stem + に (destination particle) gives the meaning of "in order to".

So, "He went (somewhere) to eat sushi (and hasn't come back yet)".

Comment: Is 食べ really a noun though? Certainly, you can say 勝ちに行く and 負けに行く, and I think 勝ち and 負け can be nouns, but there are two pitch patterns for 勝ちに, one for the noun (LHL), the other for the verb (HLL), I guess. 勝ちにこだわる uses LHL and 勝ちに行く usually uses HLL. 勝ち can be used with particles other than に, e.g. 勝ちを掴む, 勝ちが決まる, but how about 食べ?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The definition of NOUN should be defined with more restrictions. There are a bunch of types of nouns in Japanese. 食べ can turn into 食べ物, but how about 勝ち? Moreover, I don't know a lot about pitch accent, but a difference in pitch may not necessarily mean that the word is different. I think of らしい as a hearsay or as "it seems like." I wouldn't argue they are a different word. I will make an edit, given that there are adverbial nouns, i will put 連用形 to be safe.

Comment: In general I think of 連用形 as a noun-like entity precisely because of this usage and the possibility in some cases to have a more rounded noun (勝ち).

Comment: Maybe 連用形 is sometimes more like participle than gerund.

Comment: @Detaroit I've been over this in previous answers on other questions, e.g. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/keigo-%e3%81%be%e3%81%99-after-a-noun/100297#100297, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100007/the-tense-of-osagashi/100039#100039. There are many attributes that a candidate for a "noun" could have; many sorts of word in Japanese have some but not all of them, in overlapping combinations. English basically just has nouns and gerunds; I find masu-stems to be quite analogous to English gerunds. It's only my own analysis, though.

Comment: She fell asleep while reading a book.  *While* is not a preposition and thus *reading* is not a gerund. I feel something similar about 食べ as a native speaker, but it's just my feeling.

Comment: If 食べ is nominal, then it should be 食べに{LHL}. That's how I feel. But actually it is 食べに{HLL}行く.